# Getting data from dynamically added inputtext in one row and showing it after the next inputtext in another row is added in jsf

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am working in a jsf project.
I have a table that will show a data from database and add one empty row for users to fill in info. After the first empty row is filled.(From the picture, after row No.2 is filled) a new row is dynamically added.
After the second row is filled and a third row is added, the table got updated.

I have 2 problems here.

First, if a user change totalSales from 1,000 to 2,000 when the table got updated after ajax call totalSales will go back to 1,000 again.
(If a user change totalSales from 1,000 to 2,000, I want to get a new value which is 2,000 and update data in the database later)

Second, if a user fill in info in a new added row (in this case row No.3) and when row No.4 is added, a table got updated and row No3 will show an empty row.

I want a table to be able to show a data that a user fill in or change even after a table got updated from ajax call.

Any advice? I need help. I really don't know how to do this.
Your help will be very much appreciated!

[image]

This is my code.

```
                     <p:panelGrid styleClass="panel">
                        <p:row>
                            <p:column styleClass="ui-widget-header">
                                <p:outputLabel value="No." />
                            </p:column>                 
                            <p:column styleClass="ui-widget-header">
                                <p:outputLabel value="OrderDate" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column styleClass="ui-widget-header">
                                <p:outputLabel value="TotalSales" />
                            </p:column>
                        </p:row>
                       <ui:repeat value="#{myBean.dataList}" var="list">
                        <p:row>
                            <p:column styleClass="ui-widget-header">
                                <p:outputLabel value="#{list.orderNo}" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column>
                                <p:inputText value="#{list.orderDate}"/>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column >
                                <p:inputText value="#{list.totalSales}" >
                                    <p:ajax event="blur" update="@(.panel)" listener="#{myBean.addLine(orderNo)}"/>
                                </p:inputText>
                            </p:column>
                        </p:row>
                      </ui:repeat>
                    </p:panelGrid>
```

Backing Bean

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class myBean extends UpBaseBean {


@Setter
@Getter
private orderDTO dataList = new orderDTO();

.
.
.
.
.

/**
 * 
 */
@UpBackingBean
public void addLine(final int orderNo) {
    
    salesDTO dto = new salesDTO();

    dto.setShikanName(shikanName);
    dto.setOrderDate("");
    dto.setTotalSales("");
    dataList.getSalesData.add(dto); 
      }

 }
```

DTO

```
 @Getter
 @Setter
 public class orderDTO extends BaseDTO {

       List<salesDTO> salesData = new ArrayList();
 }

 @Getter
 @Setter
 public class salesDTO extends BaseDTO {

     public int orderNo;

     public Date orderDate;

     public String totalSales;
}
```

Comment: In `p:ajax` you're updating the whole panel, without processing the value within(), so they return to the server-side state. You could process every single `inputText` on event change, or process all the form in your ajax. You should consider also switching to another component, maybe an editable data table.

Comment: thank you! I got it working by adding process to the component